# Where is it mentioned that Gon didn't get his Nen back after being healed by Something/Nanika?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I watched the entire Hunter x Hunter series and I've just noticed that it is not stated whether Gon got his Nen back after being healed by Nanika or not. And I'm curios... once he jumped so high on the Wolrd Tree (we also have to notice the speed) is it possible that his Nen was restored? It would be impossible for a person with the qualities of an avarage human to jump so high/be so fast after all...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [wikia](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Alluka_Zoldyck) :

> According to Killua, the degree of wish that Nanika can grant is probably infinite

Killua ask her to "turn gon back to normal" so Nanika saved Gon turn him back to a "normal" kid, he nen is closed now. Ging say this to Gon in the chapter 345 he had returned to normal.

[image: GING ON GON'S AURA]

Comment: Your image is miniscule and impossible to read.

Comment: sorry i will put a link

Comment: Please don't post links to illegal 3rd party aggregators.

Comment: Btw what does "when I was with you it was coming out fine" really means? It means that his father could see it when they met for the first time? If he could see it then he actually didn't loose it all... he still haves a little bit of aura, but not as much as he had before (otherwise his father wouldn't have said "That's plenty", right?)

Comment: When Ging said that Gon has gone back to a normal life,  he probably meant an ordinary person. Every person has aura, though not everyone can sense it.

Comment: Yes, Gon can't sense his aura because he is in the level before started to training his nen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Gon's aura is still there just not nearly as much as before. i think he gets it back or something because after Gon meets his dad and he and Killua split ways, Gon and his father fight together in the Dark Continent Arch. I'm not sure what happens in that arch yet because I haven't read the manga just yet.